# Prove that -- the range $R(T)$ of a bounded linear operator $T:X\to Y$ need not be closed in $Y$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Prove that the range $R(T)$ of a bounded linear operator $T:X\to Y$ need not be closed in $Y$.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE! Please add your thoughts on how to approach the problem and we will be glad to give some hints.

Comment: Take a compact operator from an infinite dimensional space with infinite dimensional range.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the identity map $$\mbox{id} :\ell^1 \longrightarrow \ell^2 .$$

Comment: but $l^1$ is complete , so must be closed in $l^2$ as a subspace , then how is the range space not closed ?